# Numpy function operating on two ndarrays

Tags: python, numpy

Given two ndarrays `a = np.asarray([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])` and `b = np.asarray([[6,7,8],[9,10,11]])`I want to write a function that iterates over a and b, such that

1. [0,1,2] and [6,7,8] are considered
2. [3,4,5] and [9,10,11] are considered

An example would be a functionn that takes

1. [0,1,2] and [6,7,8] as an input and outputs 0*6+1*7+2*8 = 23
2. [3,4,5] and [9,10,11] as an input and outputs 3*9+4*10+5*11 = 122

-> (23,122)

Is there any way to do this efficiently in numpy? 
My idea was to zip both arrays, however, this is not efficient.

Edit: I am looking for a way to apply a customizable function `myfunc(x,y)`. In the previous example `myfunc(x,y)` corresponded to the multipication.

Comment: Do hadamard product and then sum along axis=1: np.sum(a*b, axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
c = a * b 
sum1 = c[0].sum()
sum2 = c[1].sum()
```

if you want the algorithmic way ( custom function )

```
a = np.asarray([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
b = np.asarray([[6,7,8],[9,10,11]])


for i in range(a.shape[0]) : 
  s = 0
  for j in range(a.shape[1]) :
    s = s + a[i][j]*b[i][j]
  print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: the proper output]
    import numpy as np
    a = np.asarray([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
    b = np.asarray([[6,7,8],[9,10,11]])
    c = a*b
    print(sum(c[0]),sum(c[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRq9W.png)))
    ans->23,122

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to use zip both array, you need to understand numpy package help you work well with matrix. So you need the basic knowledge about matrix, i recommend you learn from this link http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/ , from cs231n of Stanford university.
This is a function can solve your problem:

```
 import numpy as np
 def interates(matrix_a, matrix_b):
    product = matrix_a*matrix_b
    return (np.sum(product,1))
```

The value product contain a new matrix with same shape of matrix_a and matrix_b, each element in there is the result of `matrix_a[i][j] * matrix_b[i][j]`with i and j run from 0 to `matrix_a.shape[0]`and `matrix_a.shape[1]`.

Now check with your example

```
a = np.asarray([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
b = np.asarray([[6,7,8],[9,10,11]])
result = interates(a,b)
```

Print result

```
>> print(result)
>> [23 122]
```

If you want a tuple

```
>> result = tuple(result)
>> print(result)
>> (23, 122)
```